# Duplication of Users - Swift / Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have just gotten back into **Swift** coding and wanted to ask a question regarding duplicating values. My code flow for each observe event is as follows:

Retrieve user membership type -> Find all user names that have this membership using membership type of current user -> Find all users keys using the username from previous step -> Display username into table by searching for those users by their user id.

ISSUE:

Since the number of rows are dynamic, how do I utilise the deleteRows function to ensure that no duplication has occurred?

I would really appreciate some input. Thanks

```
func fetchUsers() {
                
guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    
databaseRef.child("users/(userId)/UserDetails/code").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { code in
   let codeOfUser = codeOfUser.value as! String
   self.databaseRef.child("code/\(codeOfUser)").observe(.childAdded, with: { (allUsernames) in
      let allUsernamesConverted = allUsernames.value as! String
     Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: "\(allUsernamesConverted)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

for registeredUserUID in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

let registeredUserUIDConverted = registeredUserUID.key
    
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: ??, section: 0)], with: .automatic) // Unsure                                                                     
self.usersArray.removeAll()
self.usersArray.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.usersArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

})}})})})}
```

Comment: When you call `self.usersArray.removeAll()` you have to remove also all rows with `self.tableView.deleteRows(at:with:)`. And don't use *type-less* `NSDictionary`. Map it to a reasonable model.

Comment: Hey @vadian, thank you for responding back. I did try that, with the same at & with as adding the rows however it did crash with the error edited in the original post. This function is being called in my viewdidload in case that intefered with anything?

Comment: No, this cannot work. In the deleting part you have to specify one index path for each row, this means if there are 5 objects you have to specify 5 index paths. You can do that with `let indexPaths = self.usersArray.indices.map{IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}` of course **before** calling `removeAll`

Comment: Thanks for the response back. Since. the rows are dynamic dependent on users, I am unable to specify row number. I have tried to implement a theory where if rows are 0, it only appends whereas anything more delete all the rows and goes ahead to append with new amount of rows. However, does not seem to work. Am i on the right path?

Comment: I don't understand. If you call `self.usersArray.removeAll()` you are going to remove all items at indices `0..<usersArray.count`. Those indices are equal to the row numbers.

Comment: I think the issue is that I just am unsure as to how do I delete number of rows when I am unsure how many there are in the table at the moment since it is dynamic. It represents all of the users, so I am not able to replace $0 with say 5 rows. I just am unsure how do I factor in that amount of rows may change, how to ensure they are all deleted, so that I can append it again, insert rows again and make sure no duplication occurs